# Publishing ClickOnce files into an ASP.NET MVC folder using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains two projects, a ClickOnce [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application and an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 4 application. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the ClickOnce deployment files be built to a folder under the ASP.NET MVC file structure and included in the project. I am trying to do this with MSbuild if possible.

I have the following in the MVC application project file (.csproj) to publish the ClickOnce files.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionDir)\src\DeveloperClient\DeveloperClient.csproj"
             Properties="MapFileExtensions=true;Install=false;GenerateManifests=true;PublishDir=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/Content/client/"
             Targets="publish" />
  </Target>
```

Along with the following to include the generated files in the ASP.NET MVC project.

```
<Content Include="Content\client\**\*.*" />
```

The problem that I am running into is with the way that the solution builds. I get all sorts of "metadata file could not be found" type of errors, so I need a way prevent the two builds from stepping on each others toes. How would I do this?

Or, am I barking up the completely wrong tree, and I should take another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish something similar, basically wanted to publish my WPF application using ClickOnce into my MVC4 Web site which is hosted on Azure.  I found this blog post 
http://elbruno.com/2013/06/01/azure-howto-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-and-azure-website/
and am  using this method to upload my ClickOnce installer.  I'm on a WebRole, so its a slow process to update, might switch to one of the new Azure websites one of these days.